# ILogger<> convention not working in service hosted by Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am used to using the `ILogger<MyService>` convention for logging injecting this into a constructor

This works fine in App Services but not in services that are hosted by Azure Functions

There are no errors, just nothing gets logged

I have also tried the LoggerFactory approach after injecting a LoggerFactory, but that doesnt work either

```
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("test");
```

Has anyone had this issue?

Paul

Comment: Have you setup logging in startup?

Comment: Yes I added services.AddLogging in the function startup file

Comment: See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4345 _Today if someone creates a logger that is not in one of our "accepted" lists, we'll filter it away. You can get around this by adding one or more filters to get those categories flowing again…_

Comment: Ok thanks I will look when I get home

Comment: I need the ILogger<MyService> convention to work is that supported in azure functions? The function itself uses just logger but I don’t want to use that convention

Comment: Yes, it is supported. Check for [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Core/Implementation/ToDoItemsService.cs) reference. It seems that you log level declaration is either not decaled or higher log level. Check your host.json file and update the default to `information` like --- `"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }`